# My college changed my major without my consent, can I sue them?

Tags: education, advertisements

I am a college student at a new University located in Mauritius. 
Before I applied, I checked on their website the list of major offered. I saw: "Electrical Engineering" which was one of the main reasons why I applied. 
I got a fully funded scholarship as being part of the inaugural class. 
What is different about this university is that during the first year, you do not follow a major immediately, instead, you follow a mandatory leadership training for 1 year. 
Then after my first year, the asked us to pick a major. At that time, they still had the option: "Electrical Engineering" which I immediately picked.

Then 4 months later, when I came back to Mauritius after the annual break, they announced that the "Electrical Engineering" degree now became "Electrical POWER SYSTEMS Engineering" . Being confused, as there were no other options available and I was not ready to drop out, I followed that major because no other degree were closed to why I came to this college initially. This Electrical and Power systems engineering was the only close option to Electrical Engineering. It has been 2 years now and I realised that the content of the degree is diverging really far from what is actually "Electrical Engineering" .

I really want to drop out now but I feel that I have been a victim of "false advertising". And the consequence is that I wasted 2 years of my life following a degree that I don't like, not passionate about and not all field that I want to pursue my career on later. My college changed my major without my consent, can I sue them?

Comment: You got a full fully funded scholarship to a new university and you want to sue them for changing Electrical Engineering to Electrical Power Systems Engineering?  Did you not get 2 years of credits you can transfer?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know too much about Mauritian contract law, but I'd assume you'd have to identify some legal obligation that the school breached. Here, the school offered you a full ride in its electrical engineering program, and has delivered on its promise. The fact that you don't like the program anymore probably doesn't make then liable for anything.

In terms of false advertising, it's hard to say anything without seeing their advertisements.